# How to create a wrapper widget and pass children and properties to it in flutter

Tags: flutter, layout

I have two pages with the same layout

In react I would create a wrapper, import it and pass the children, so both pages share the same wrapper.

```
<Wrapper someproperty={1}>
  <div>content page 1</div>
</Wrapper>

<Wrapper someproperty={2}>
  <div>content page 2</div>
</Wrapper>
```

Is there an equivalent for this in flutter? Any other option is very welcome, like a shared class or something, thank you

Comment: You can do that in flutter by creating your own widgets. The stateless widgets of flutter are like functional components in react and the stateful ones are like class components. The basic idea remains the same. For example, create a stateful class and add props just like you do in react. This might help you get started:  https://www.raywenderlich.com/10126984-creating-reusable-custom-widgets-in-flutter

Comment: @AfridiKayal thank you, it is very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I used the Class MetaData.

The documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MetaData-class.html

Example of usage:

```
class CustomText extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomText({
    Key key,
    this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final WrapperWidget wrapperWidget = context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType();
    return Text(
      "text ${wrapperWidget.metaData.toString()}" ??
          wrapperWidget.metaData.toString(),
    );
  }
}

class WrapperWidget extends MetaData {
  const WrapperWidget({
    Widget child,
    int someProperty,
  }) : super(
          child: child,
          metaData: someProperty,
        );
}


/// declaration
final component = WrapperWidget(
            child: CustomText(text: "content page"), someProperty: 1);
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know you could do this.

Answer (score 1):

Of course.
Create a Stateful-Widget which is your Wrapper. Extend this Widget with flag i.e. an int-value. Also extend this Wrapper with a function to switch the flag and call setState() in this function. Pass this Function to the children so they can change the value.

Wrapper:

```
class ScrnWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScrnWrapperState createState() => _ScrnWrapperState();
}

class _ScrnWrapperState extends State<ScrnWrapper> {
int flag = 0;

  _switchFlag(int newValue){
     setState(() {
       flag = newValue;
     });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return (flag == 0) ? ChildA(_switchFlag) : ChildB(_switchFlag);

  }
}
```

Child A / B

```
class ChildA extends StatelessWidget {
 
  final Function _switchFlag;

  WdgtAnwurfOverviewTeam(
    this._switchFlag,
  );
}
```

Now you can call the _switchFlag from the child-Widget. The state is updating and the tree is rebuild with your desired content.

Comment: Thank you. It is so hard flutter